# How to handle the bug in Maple latex command?

Tags: command-line, latex, maple

In Windows 7, I need to use Maple to export the Tex code into a text file.

In Command-line Maple, I type `latex(LambertW(x), "C:/Users/Bravo/Desktop/out.txt");` to do this, but the result is:

> {\rm W} \left(x\right)

That is not right, why does it happen ? Is there any method to solve this problem ?

Comment: If you want the name to appear the same (rather than lowercase, etc) you could instead substitute with a generated local symbol. Eg, 
`latex(subs([LambertW=\`tools/gensym\`(LambertW)],LambertW(x)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, that is a bug in Maple. You can try `latex(subs(LambertW=lambertW,erf=Erf,arctanh=Artanh,LambertW(x)));`

Reference: http://www.mapleprimes.com/questions/201975-Maple-Error-Using-Latex-Command-How-To-Resolve#comment207767